# Using COUNT on a self join query

Tags: mysql

I have a query that populates a double select list. The query retrieves main categories and sub categories from the same table via a self join. Basically it joins itself to get the subcategories in each category using id and parent id. I have tried to use COUNT to get the number of subcategories so I can add the number to the output of the first list. I didn't write the query , I just want to refactor it to count the subs in each main.

```
SELECT 
    root.name AS root_name, 
    root.link AS root_link, 
    root.RETAIL AS root_RETAIL, 
    root.WHOLESALE AS root_WHOLESALE,
    root.linkto AS root_linkto, 
    root.keywords AS root_keywords, 
    root.description AS root_description, 
    root.id AS root_id,
    down1.name AS down1_name,
    down1.linkto AS down1_linkto, 
    down1.link AS down1_link, 
    down1.keywords AS down1_keywords,
    down1.description AS down1_description, 
    down1.id AS down1_id, 
    down1.parentid AS down1_parentid, 
    down1.RETAIL AS down1_RETAIL, 
    down1.WHOLESALE AS down1_WHOLESALE
FROM categories AS root
        LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS down1 ON down1.parentid = root.id
WHERE root.parentid = 0
ORDER BY root_name, down1_name
```

This returns everything to populate both lists. I try to surround either `down1_name` or `down1_id` with `COUNT` but it counts everything - not the number of subs in each main. I'm not sure about using another self join to do it or a nested `SELECT` with `COUNT`. Any insight would be much appreciated. Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a subquery

```
SELECT r.name AS r_name, 
       r.link AS r_link, 
       r.RETAIL AS r_RETAIL, 
       r.WHOLESALE AS r_WHOLESALE,
       r.linkto AS r_linkto, 
       r.keywords AS r_keywords, 
       r.description AS r_description, 
       r.id AS r_id,
       d.name AS d_name,
       d.linkto AS d_linkto, 
       d.link AS d_link, 
       d.keywords AS d_keywords,
       d.description AS d_description, 
       d.id AS d_id, 
       d.parentid AS d_parentid, 
       d.RETAIL AS d_RETAIL, 
       d.WHOLESALE AS d_WHOLESALE,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM categories 
         WHERE parentid = r.id) d_count
  FROM categories AS r LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS d 
    ON d.parentid = r.id
 WHERE r.parentid = 0
 ORDER BY r_name, d_name
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4de04c/15)**

Comment: This returns a syntax error , trying to sort it out. I tried something similar and got the same. Tks!

Comment: @Steve Sorry, it was just one omitted comma after `d.WHOLESALE AS d_WHOLESALE,`. See updated answer and [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4de04c/15)

Comment: Ahh I put one in but also used AS in front of d_count. Works Great! Many Thanks!

Comment: Also , when I tried this on my own before this post , again, I used AS after the nested SELECT for my alias name where yours is d_count. Not realizing I didn't need it.

Comment: @Steve You're more than welcome :) `AS` is optional. For consistency in your query you can use it in front of d_count.

Answer (score 1):

If you try something like this??

```
select count(cs.down1_name) as mycount from
    (
    SELECT root.name AS root_name, 
    root.link AS root_link, 
    root.RETAIL AS root_RETAIL, 
    root.WHOLESALE AS root_WHOLESALE,
    root.linkto AS root_linkto, 
    root.keywords AS root_keywords, 
    root.description AS root_description, 
    root.id AS root_id,
    down1.name AS down1_name,
    down1.linkto AS down1_linkto, 
    down1.link AS down1_link, 
    down1.keywords AS down1_keywords,
    down1.description AS down1_description, 
    down1.id AS down1_id, 
    down1.parentid AS down1_parentid, 
    down1.RETAIL AS down1_RETAIL, 
    down1.WHOLESALE AS down1_WHOLESALE
    FROM categories AS root
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS down1 ON down1.parentid = root.id
    WHERE root.parentid = 0
    ORDER BY root_name, down1_name ) as cs
    group by cs.down1_name
```

-----------------UPDATE-------------------------------------

Something like this?:

```
SELECT cat_a.name, 
   cat_a.link, 
   cat_a.RETAIL, 
   cat_a.WHOLESALE,
   cat_a.linkto, 
   cat_a.keywords, 
   cat_a.description, 
   cat_a.id,
   cat_b.name cat_b_name,
   cat_b.linkto cat_b_linkto, 
   cat_b.link cat_b_link, 
   cat_b.keywords cat_b_keywords,
   cat_b.description cat_b_description, 
   cat_b.id cat_b_id, 
   cat_b.parentid cat_b_parentid, 
   cat_b.RETAIL cat_b_RETAIL, 
   cat_b.WHOLESALE cat_b_WHOLESALE,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM categories 
     WHERE parentid = cat_a.id) as cat_b_count
FROM categories cat_a LEFT OUTER JOIN categories cat_b 
ON (cat_b.parentid = cat_a.id)
WHERE cat_a.parentid = 0
```

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4de04c/11

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He needs to return the other columns too, not just a `count`.

Comment: He can execute both queries in a separate way, or adapt this one to fullfill his requeriment.

Comment: The query above returns a *single* count, whereas he is looking for a count *per parent* like in @peterm's example.

Comment: A single count....did you see this group by cs.down1_name, at the end of the query??

Comment: Nope, I totally missed it. I have not tested it, but I am pretty sure grouping by `cs.down1_name` still won't return the right counts ... (see the original question). Did you test it?

Comment: I'm waiting for the user to provide a sqlfiddle with sample data....he ask for an aswer 4 hours ago, and he hasnt post any comment...i think i'm gonna wait a little bit more.

Comment: Hi guys, The original query returns everything , and would be duplicate rows except for the left outer join which ties in the subcat info. So it appears like: Animals - Dinosaur,Animals- Fish, Animals- Monkeys ect ... Of course I am leaving out all the other fields but you get my point. So it works great for a double select list , I just wanted to count the subs somehow and output the number in parenthesis after the main cat in the first list. Not crucial just a nice to have. It seemed easy enough in theory but after trying , it's a little complicated but I like a challenge. Tks.

Comment: Here's a SQL Fiddle link. I had to customize the insert for Fiddle obviously because the top 10 rows from the table would return null on the left outer join but you can see what I mean - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4de04c/1

Comment: Now where I have seen that before ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier with query of queries.  Something like this (we'll assume the main query is named q1).

```
<cfquery name="q2" dbtype="query">
select r_id maincat
, count(*) subcategories
from q1
where d_name is not null
group by r_id
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="q3" dbtype="query">
select q1.*
, subcategories
from q1, q2
where r_id = maincat
</cfquery>
```

Then use q3 to populate your lists instead of q1.

Comment: I considered using this method in the CF code since it's nice and encapsulated and if I can get the right count , just create a variable for it and output that way. Nothing yet but I was querying off of the original query. tks!